# parent and child json tree for d3.js in powerbi

Tags: javascript

I am building customer visual right now using power bi D3.js Visual. 
D3 in power bi gives me the following JSON as input :

```
 var arr = [
{ "source" : "BBB", "target" : "AAA"},
{ "source" : "CCC ", "target" : "BBB"},
{ "source" : "DDDD", "target" : "AAA"},
{ "source" : "SSSS", "target" : "CCC"},
{ "source" : "EEEE", "target" : "BBB"},
{ "source" : "FFFF", "target" : "DDDD"},
```

But what I need is:

```
var arr = 

{
  "source": "AAA",
  "children": [
    { 
      "source": "BBB",
      "children": [
        { "source": "CCC",
           "children": [
               { "source": "SSSS"] },
        { "source": "EEEE" }
      ]
    },
    { "source": "DDDD",
      "children": [
        { "source": "FFFF" },
     ] },

  ]
}
```

Can someone help one to get this format in javascript?

I tired with following script that I find on other posts, I made some small changes already,just cant get to work.

```
function unflatten(arr) {
  var tree = [],
      mappedArr = {},
      arrElem,
      mappedElem;

  // First map the nodes of the array to an object -> create a hash table.
  for(var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    arrElem = arr[i];
    mappedArr[arrElem.child] = arrElem;
    mappedArr[arrElem.child]['children'] = [];
  }



  for (var id in mappedArr) {
    if (mappedArr.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
    console.log(mappedArr.hasOwnProperty(id))
      mappedElem = mappedArr[id];
      //console.log(mappedElem)
      // If the element is not at the root level, add it to its parent array of children.
      if (mappedElem.parent!="0") {
        mappedArr[mappedElem['parent']]['children'].push(mappedElem);
      }
      // If the element is at the root level, add it to first level elements array.
      else {
        tree.push(mappedElem);
      }
    }
  }
  return tree;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this, here is just one:

```js
const arr = [
  { source: "BBB", target: "AAA" },
  { source: "CCC", target: "BBB" },
  { source: "DDDD", target: "AAA" },
  { source: "SSSS", target: "CCC" },
  { source: "EEEE", target: "BBB" },
  { source: "FFFF", target: "DDDD" }
];

const trunk = arr.find(x => !arr.some(y => y.source === x.target)).target;

const branches = arr.reduce((acc, x) => {
  acc[x.target] = acc[x.target] || [];
  acc[x.target].push(x.source);
  return acc;
}, {});

const tree = buildTree(trunk, branches);

function buildTree(source, branches) {
  const tree = { source };
  if (branches[source]) {
    tree.children = branches[source].map(x => buildTree(x, branches));
  }
  return tree;
}

console.log("Trunk: ", trunk);
console.log("Branches: ", branches);
console.log("Output: ", JSON.stringify(tree, null, 2));
```

The idea is that you:

1. Find the trunk of the tree
2. Find all branches that have children
3. Build the tree, starting from the trunk and fill every branch with its children recursively

Further clarifications:

`arr.find(x => !arr.some(y => y.source === x.target))` looks for a branch that has no father

The [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test. In this case, since it has a `!`, it will test that no element in the array has a father.

The [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method returns the value of the first branch that has no father.

In the case you consider having multiple trunks you can substitute the `find()` method with a `filter()` method, which will return an array of all the trunks. Then you would have to modify the algorithm like this:

```js
const arr = [
  { source: "BBB", target: "AAA" },
  { source: "CCC", target: "BBB" },
  { source: "DDDD", target: "AAA" },
  { source: "SSSS", target: "CCC" },
  { source: "EEEE", target: "BBB" },
  { source: "FFFF", target: "DDDD" },
  { source: "XXXX", target: "YYYY" }
];

const trunks = arr.filter(x => !arr.some(y => y.source === x.target));

const branches = arr.reduce((acc, x) => {
  acc[x.target] = acc[x.target] || [];
  acc[x.target].push(x.source);
  return acc;
}, {});

const trees = trunks.map(x => buildTree(x.target, branches));

function buildTree(source, branches) {
  const tree = { source };
  if (branches[source]) {
    tree.children = branches[source].map(x => buildTree(x, branches));
  }
  return tree;
}

console.log("Trunk: ", trunks);
console.log("Branches: ", branches);
console.log("Output: ", JSON.stringify(trees, null, 2));
```

Comment: Hi, I am very new to js. Just wondering can you explain a bit about this line:
const trunk = arr.find(x => !arr.some(y => y.source === x.target)).target;

And Thank you again helping me

Comment: And also what happen where there are multiple trunk

Comment: I edited the answer with "further clarifications" and added a code snippet for the multiple trunks case

Comment: I made some change to suit my additional requirement, but it perfect works. Great solution. thanks

Comment: Sorry to come back to you again, just wondering any way can add attribute to it. For example, it might have description for each, and the description is source's attribute. Thank you